# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) Laravel - PHP - AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, cors

Estoy tratando de hacer una solicitud simple de origen cruzado, y Chrome la bloquea constantemente con este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si envió la solicitud sin la petición AJAX, ósea pego directamente la URL al navegador me genera una respuesta correcta.

```
           url: "http://tablas.sispro.gov.co/WSSUMMIPRESNOPBS/api/GenerarToken/555555271/TOKEN_PROV/",
           method: "GET",
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           dataType: "jsonp",          
           success: function(respuesta){

               console.log(respuesta);

           }

       });
```

Lo que puedo entender según la consola del navegador es que la API si genera la respuesta, pero al momento de enviar la respuesta al navegador esté la bloquea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su atención y la respuesta que puedan dar al fallo.

Cordialmente,
Yeison F. Cardenas

Comment: "Por razones de seguridad, los exploradores restringen las solicitudes HTTP de origen cruzado iniciadas dentro de un script. Por ejemplo, XMLHttpRequest y la API Fetch siguen la política de mismo-origen. Ésto significa que una aplicación que utilice esas APIs XMLHttpRequest sólo puede hacer solicitudes HTTP a su propio dominio, a menos que se utilicen cabeceras CORS." Link de referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Entonces posibles soluciones: agregar las cabeceras cors en "tablas.sispro.gov.co" --o-- utilizar algún proxy --o-- subir el archivo a un servidor y probar --o-- hacer la solicitud desde PHP y probar ;)

Comment: Gracias compañero por tmarse el tiempo para responder a mi inquietud. En efecto cuando realizo la solicitud desde php se genera la respuesta correctamente, el punto es que la pagina oficial de la API indica que recibe peticiones con JSON y no lo he logrado.

Comment: Hice algunas pruebas y no :(. Solo con PHP funciona. No se si tendras algun link a la documentacion que quizas indique alguna configuracion especial. Por ahora tienes que hacer la peticion con PHP y si lo haces con ajax, tienes que hacer la peticion a tu servidor para que el haga la peticion a la "api", se entiende? eso!

Comment: De nuevo muchas gracias por prestar atención a mi inquietud.

Link de la API
(https://tablas.sispro.gov.co/WSSUMMIPRESNOPBS/Help/Api/GET-api-GenerarToken-nit-token)

Link de la Documentación:
(https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Lists/BibliotecaDigital/RIDE/DE/OT/Documentacion-web-services-V-3.1.pdf)

En mi búsqueda encontré que el fallo esta dado por los encabezado CORS y se indica que debo generar una petición por medio de otra API:  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40527186)

Comment: Sí. Solo queda recibir los datos con PHP